# Find password to a word document

Tags: java, performance, com

I am using Java and COM4j to communicate with Word. The approach I used here is brute force. I have a password protected `.doc`, and I forgot its password.

Complexity is (26)<sup>(`maxPassLength`)</sup>. [a-z characters only]

Before I run this code and wait for 7-10 days here are my concerns.

My main concern is checking whether a generated string matches the password. Is there any alternative to this? Would you recommend threading to reduce the search space?

```
import com4j.Variant;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import word.Documents;
import word.WdOpenFormat;
import word._Application;
import word._Document;

public class DocPasswordFinder {

    public final static String filePath2 = "\\file\\abc.doc";
    private static HashMap<Integer, Character> mapC;
    private static final int passMaxLength;
    public static  _Application app;
    public static Documents doc;
    public static char[] arr;

    static {
    passMaxLength=9;
    arr = new char[passMaxLength];
    app = word.ClassFactory.createApplication();
    doc = app.documents();
    mapC=new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
            mapC.put(i, (char) ('a' + i));
        }
    }

    public static void genPass(int start, int indx) {
        if (indx == passMaxLength) {
            String PASSWORD = String.valueOf(arr);
            try {                
        doc.open2000(filePath, false, true, false, PASSWORD, "", false,   
    PASSWORD, "", WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatAuto, false, false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FOUND: " + PASSWORD);
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (com4j.ComException ex) {
                //continue;
            }
        } else {
            if (indx < arr.length) {
                for (int i = start; i < 26; ++i) {
                    arr[indx] = mapC.get(i);
                    genPass(start, indx + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        genPass(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Bottleneck appears to be the `doc.open2000()` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Complexity is (26)<sup>(maxPassLength).</sup>

You know that the password is only lower-case alpha characters?

> Would you recommend threading to reduce the search space?

It's possible that threads wouldn't help. The `doc.open2000` will be more expensive than anything else, and your communication with Word may (I don't know) be effectively single-threaded (i.e. talking to a single Word process/task).

You might get better performance from a Word emulator which is designed to run on a server, e.g. from http://www.aspose.com/

Comment: Yes i do know that. Hence 26(lower case alpha characters) in `maxPassLength` positions (26^`maxPassLength`). It is supposed to work for my doc file.

Comment: That sounds like 10^14 possible combinations. To do all those in 10 days you would need to do 2 x 10^7 per second.

Comment: @boxed__l I can't answer that question and it's off-topic on this site. [You might find an answer here](http://superuser.com/search?q=word+password).

Comment: @boxed__l Its behaviour is allegedly described here: http://www.password-crackers.com/crack/guaword.html I think that implies something like: a) Know Word document format well enough to extract encrypted password from the document; b) Know the (one-way) encryption algorithm; c) Use the PC's GPU (video card) to iterate-and-encrypt 2^40 possible password guesses to find a password which (when encrypted) will match the document's encrypted password.